# Was parity multisig exploit fixed?

Tags: parity, multisignature

I want to use parity as a multisig wallet, but I want to make sure they've already fixed the recent exploit.
Most articles online just talk about the exploit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was fixed on Jul 19, [this](https://github.com/paritytech/parity/pull/6102) is the Pull Request.

As stated in their [release notes](https://github.com/paritytech/parity/releases), you need to make sure your parity version is `1.6.10` or above.

[Here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/21618/what-is-the-exploit-behind-paritys-multisig-wallet-from-2017-07-19) is a post explaining the exploit, you can check for yourself that now there is a `only_uninitialized` modifier in the constructor.

Update: As of 11/7/2017, all Parity multi-sig wallets deployed after July 20th have no functionality [(source)](https://paritytech.io/blog/security-alert.html). An unknown user took control of Parity's library contract from which all Parity multi-sig wallets derived functionality. The user then unwittingly suicided the library contract, obliterating all wallet functionality and freezing ~500 wallets, and about ~$150M [(source)](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/21618/what-is-the-exploit-behind-paritys-multisig-wallet-from-2017-07-19). This won't be resolved until after a hard fork.

A good explanation of events can be found [here.](https://blog.springrole.com/parity-multi-sig-wallets-funds-frozen-explained-768ac072763c)

Comment: Addendum in light of recent events (11/7/2017): another critical security bug was discovered when a user unwittingly took control of Parity's multi-sig library contract, from which every multi-sig wallet deployed after July 20th derived functionality. The user then suicided the contract, obliterating all functionality for ~500 Parity multi-sig wallets, and freezing ~$150M. This bug won't be fixed (for currently existing multi-sig wallets) until after a hard fork occurs that allows them to restore the library contract, or move the funds.